# Java script to display partial value of the select tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm very new to javascript but I want to write a script for a select tag (for countries and their phone codes). I want it such that the dropdown list shows the country and code, but after the user selects only the code should be displayed. I'm using PHP to write the webpage. Thanks

Comment: Ok. That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do/requirements lists.

Comment: I'm asking for an idea on how to do it.

Comment: @MarcB Hey now, be nice. But it's true, this question is rather open-ended and likely has good answers elsewhere on StackOverflow or the internet in general. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for more info about what questions are a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best for you is to use a JQuery method as the following codes.

Your HTML would be like the following.

```
<select>
  <option value="01" textValue="America">01</option>
  <option value="02" textValue="Liberia">02</option>
  <option value="03" textValue="Switzerland">03</option>
</select>
```

```
$("your select").on('focus', function(){
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        var text = $(this).attr('textValue') + ' - ' + $(this).attr('value');
        $(this).text(text);
    });
});

$("your select").on('blur', function(){
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).attr('value'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a life saver. I appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want here is something like this

```html
<select>
  <option value="01">America - 01</option>
  <option value="02">Liberia - 02</option>
  <option value="03">Switzerland - 03</option>
</select>
```

You can use click event for selecting in javascript, not quite sure of how you are planning to use those select..

Comment: no. op wants 'America - 01` in the list, then once you actually select that option, only `01` shows in the select.

Comment: Hi Aaron, my goal is for it to work like that of the Yahoo signup page. Marc B is right

Comment: @Marc B since you understand me, please help me. At least if its not possible with javascript, tell me. I'm trying to learn from you here please.